# Back branches in code

Tags: c, design, safety, programming, assembly

While reading [this](https://msquair.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/dealing-with-software-hazards.pdf) file on software hazards this slide says:

[image]

"No Back Branch in the Code"

I wonder what does it mean? Normally when we write code in C-language then we don't actually do branching explicitly as in the case of assembly language programming. Does it mean that the above design rule is only possible to follow at assembly level and not at the c-level programming?

Comment: Likely assembly only or some specialized language. Any loop or function call may introduce "back-branches". The guidelines seem to be ridiculously constraining.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a strictly software question.

Comment: The rule means when using C-language, the compiler shall not use back branching. I wonder if such compiler existed/exists, so, it's likely they couldn't use C-language

Comment: If this wasn't hand-coded assembly, it is almost assuredly Ada.

Comment: Or in other words - "Don't use C language, use our primitive language called ADA"

Comment: "The guidelines seem to be ridiculously constraining".  Not for life-critical stuff.  Unless you don't mind the idea of jetliners full of people falling out of the sky because of software bugs.

Comment: @MituRaj Ada is not "primitive" in the least bit. It is extremely advanced for its time (and even now) and modern systems still rely on it, [most of the F-35 fighter software is written in Ada](https://craftofcoding.wordpress.com/2016/03/07/the-f-35-jet-fighter-is-programmed-using-what/). 99% of the flight software on the Boeing 777 is Ada... Ada was created by the US DoD.

Comment: @TimWescott I happened to be involved in the design of some life-critical stuff. These guidelines are outdated at best. Today we have pretty sophisticated analysis and design techniques allowing to effectively use modern programming languages and processors.

Comment: @RonBeyer I would say C is more primitive than Ada :) But from my knowledge of it I am not sure how can it enforce the "no back branching" constraint.

Comment: It should be noted that not only does the code itself need to be reviewed and certified, the *tool chain* must also be certified (leading to rather expensive tool chains).

Comment: These claims are contradictory. They say there is no back branch, but still mention a loop. It looks like a gross oversimplification.

Comment: @dim I think they mean "exactly one back branch in the entire program".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back branches create loops. And any module that contains a loop becomes subject to the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) — to wit, you cannot write a program that can **in all cases** determine whether the module will exit the loop.

When you're writing software for real-time systems that have hard deadlines, you want to be able to prove that the deadlines are always met. Modules without loops have definite execution times for every path through the code. Modules with loops do not.

There are of course, broad classes of code with loops for which you CAN predict a maximum execution time, so this theoretical constraint is overly restrictive in the context of modern tools.

Answer (score 0):

Manually writing safety-critical code in assembler is considered dangerous practice nowadays (by for example IEC 61508), since having complete low-level access to everything makes it too easy to create bugs. This is not what that document refers to.

Rather, "no back branches" means that safety-critical *high level language code* is not allowed to have any *non-conditional branching upwards* in high level code. "High level language" in this context means either C or Ada, where only a safe subset of the language is used. Other languages aren't considered suitable.

How to write the code is regulated by industry standards like MISRA-C and DO-178, which in turn explicitly ban non-conditional branching upwards.

Example with goto:

```
loop:
...

goto loop; // non-conforming
```

Example with continue:

```
while(x)
{
  if(something)
    continue;   // non-conforming
  ...
}
```

The above is not necessarily incorrect code, but it could have been written in different ways. The problem is that it could lead to "spaghetti programming". Safety standards seek to eliminate hazards and that's why they ban such branching completely.

And as it turns out, the presence of these keywords is often a clear indication of badly written loops that could be simplified - it is "code smell".

Now of course the automatically generated assembler will contain branches upwards, but that's another story, related to compiler validation etc.